# My Shader Nodes are not exporting Blender

Tags: materials, shaders, unity, shader-nodes

I made a 3d model on blender and created materials with using Shader Nodes (I dont know how to call them i just made material on Shader Editor).

[image]

When i export the model and put it on the Unity well... some of the materials did not work.

[image]

I looked what did i miss and i relized the broken materials are the one i made by Shader Nodes
(The water and big ground!)
(I just selected and assigned materials on trees so they work :P)

The Ground
[image]
And the water
[image]

I realy dont get what to do about this...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures) Although you don't bother to tell us what kind of export you are doing, I guess the answer there will hint at the reason why it's not working for you. Whatever software/file format you are exporting to, it is most likely or almost certain that they don't have the same shader system as Blender.

Comment: Hi, Berk, Please edit to include the export method, as suggested. if @GordonBrinkmann's suggestion works for you, could you let us know in the comments, here, please?

Comment: its fbx sorry i couldnt reply @RobinBetts also i relised there is a problem with unity... it just not seeing materials made with shader nodes in blender